# Using apply over two lists of different lengths

Tags: r

This question is related to my earlier question found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089532/r-accounting-for-a-factor-with-this-logistic-regression-function-replace-lappl

I realize that I didn't do a good job at asking the first question, so here is a more simple analog with actual data:

My data looks something like this:

```
#data look like this, but with a variable number of "y" columms
wk<-rep(1:50,2)
X<-rnorm(1:100,1)
y1<-rnorm(1:100,1) 
y2<-rnorm(1:100,1)

df1<-as.data.frame(cbind(wk,X,y1,y2))
df1$hyst<-ifelse(df1$wk>=5 & df1$wk<32, "R", "F")

Y<-df1[, -which(colnames(df1) %in% c("wk"))] #this step makes more sense with my actual data since I have a bunch of columns to remove  
l1<-length(Y)-1
lst1<-lapply(2:l1,function(x){colnames(Y[x])}) 
dflst<-c("Y",'Y[Y$hyst=="R",]','Y[Y$hyst=="F",]')
```

I want to run a model over all Y columns for the full data set (all data) and for two subsets, when the factor hyst=="R" and when hyst=="F".
To do this, I have nested two lapply functions, which sort of works, but I think it essentially doubles my results and is causing me all sorts of list headaches.

Here is the nested lapply code:

```
lms <- lapply(dflst, function(z){
          lapply(lst1, function(y) {
form <- paste0(y, " ~ X")
lm(form, data=eval(parse(text=z)))
 })
})
```

How can I replace or modify the nested lapply function to obtain a model run for each Y column for each data set( all, "R", and "F")?

Comment: The object `dflst` is quite strange. Don't write commands in quotes; just write the commands.

Answer (score 0):

Construct your DF list like

```
DFlst <- c(list(full=Y), split(Y, Y$hyst))

str(DFlst)

List of 3
 $ full:'data.frame':   100 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ X   : num [1:100] 1.792 3.192 0.367 1.632 1.388 ...
  ..$ y1  : num [1:100] 3.354 1.189 1.99 0.639 0.1 ...
  ..$ y2  : num [1:100] 0.864 2.415 0.437 1.069 1.368 ...
  ..$ hyst: chr [1:100] "F" "F" "F" "F" ...
 $ F   :'data.frame':   46 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ X   : num [1:46] 1.792 3.192 0.367 1.632 0.707 ...
  ..$ y1  : num [1:46] 3.354 1.189 1.99 0.639 0.894 ...
  ..$ y2  : num [1:46] 0.864 2.415 0.437 1.069 1.213 ...
  ..$ hyst: chr [1:46] "F" "F" "F" "F" ...
 $ R   :'data.frame':   54 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ X   : num [1:54] 1.388 2.296 0.409 1.494 0.943 ...
  ..$ y1  : num [1:54] 0.1002 0.6425 -0.0918 1.199 0.8767 ...
  ..$ y2  : num [1:54] 1.368 1.122 0.402 -0.237 1.518 ...
  ..$ hyst: chr [1:54] "R" "R" "R" "R" ...
```

Do some regressions:

```
res <- lapply(DFlst, function(DF) {
  cols =  grep("^y[0-9]+$",names(DF),value=TRUE)
  lapply(setNames(cols,cols), 
    function(y) lm(paste(y,"~X"), data=DF))
  })

str(res, list.len=2, give.attr=FALSE)

List of 3
 $ full:List of 2
  ..$ y1:List of 12
  .. ..$ coefficients : Named num [1:2] 0.903 0.111
  .. ..$ residuals    : Named num [1:100] 2.2509 -0.0698 1.046 -0.4464 -0.9578 ...
  .. .. [list output truncated]
  ..$ y2:List of 12
  .. ..$ coefficients : Named num [1:2] 1.423 -0.166
  .. ..$ residuals    : Named num [1:100] -0.2623 1.5213 -0.9253 -0.0837 0.1751 ...
  .. .. [list output truncated]
 $ F   :List of 2
  ..$ y1:List of 12
  .. ..$ coefficients : Named num [1:2] 0.9289 0.0769
  .. ..$ residuals    : Named num [1:46] 2.2871 0.0146 1.0332 -0.4157 -0.0889 ...
  .. .. [list output truncated]
  ..$ y2:List of 12
  .. ..$ coefficients : Named num [1:2] 1.4177 -0.0789
  .. ..$ residuals    : Named num [1:46] -0.413 1.25 -0.952 -0.22 -0.149 ...
  .. .. [list output truncated]
  [list output truncated]
```